# Datediff in mins, taking into account custom bank holidays, maintenance days and working hours

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (`table1`) which includes columns `[deadline]` and `[completion]`, both of datatype `datetime`.

I need to calculate the date diff in minutes between `[deadline]` and `[completion]`.

For example:

- deadline = 2018-11-22 09:05
- completion = 2018-11-22 9:10

Result needs to be 5.

However, I also need to factor in bank holidays, using a previously generated custom table, say `[tableBH]`, which has `[date] [bank holiday name]`.

Also, there is another table a maintenance table `[tableMaintenance]` with columns `[date] [maintenance reason]`.

Lastly, I working hours monday to friday are 0900 to 1900, and on saturday 1100 - 1500.

I need the datediff, ideally in minutes, to take into account non-working hours, non-working days, and bank holidays.

Ideally by way of a function. Can anyone give pointers as to where to start?

My current script only does `DATEDIFF ( mi , deadline, completion)`

Well, I say that, but it is currently a little more convoluted, but I can deal with that later.

For transparency, my current code, which does not take into account maintenance days, bank holidays, and non-working hours is:

```
CONVERT(varchar, Datediff(n, [deadline],[completion])/60) + ':' + Right('0' + CONVERT(varchar,(datediff(n,[deadline],[completion]) %60)),2)) as [TimeDIFF]
```

This format doesn't matter too much.

What matters is referencing the

- custom bank holiday table, not sys,
- custom maintenance table,
- working hours (different on a saturday to working days)
- passed through a function (in SQL Server 2017)

Sample:

TableBH - columns [date],[bank holiday name]

```
26 November 2018, FakeBH1
```

TableMaintenance - columns [date],[maintenance reason]

```
28 November 2018, FakeMaintenance1
```

table1 - columns [id], [deadline], [completion]

```
1, 2018-11-24 14:55, 2018-11-27 09:05 
2, 2018-11-24 15:05, 2018-11-27 09:04
3, 2018-11-27 11:00, 2018-11-27 10:35
4, 2018-11-27 16:50, 2018-11-29 09:10
```

> output id, duration in mins 1 = 10 2 = 4 3 = -25 4 = 20

Comment: Sample data and expected results please.

Comment: A calendar table, listing the working hours for each day (I assume that perhaps they differ at weekends?), as well as it if it is a working day seems like a good start. Have you made any attempts using your calendar tables?

Comment: Sami- Standby. Larnu- thanks

Comment: What should happen when table1 has deadline and/or completion TIMEs that are outside of working hours on those days?  Deadline of  08:22  or completion of  21:15?  Bypass and flag as error?

Comment: Or what happens when they get is done early?  Completion date/time prior to Deadline date/time?  Give them a bonus negative number of minutes?  Or deadline/completion on a holiday?

Comment: Deadline outside hours- the clock will start on the next working time. Eg 2300 deadline, 0905 completion. Output 5mins

Comment: Early completion - as row id 3- negative mins. If deadline outside hours, and completion subsequently outside hours, 0 mins. Although, this shouldn’t happen. Deadline always calculated within hours, and if an unscheduled maintenance or outage occurs, deadline is automatically updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BankDate    BankTimeStart       BankTimeEnd         WorkingMins
2018-11-19  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    720
2018-11-20  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    720
2018-11-21  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    720
2018-11-22  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    720
2018-11-23  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    720
2018-11-24  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    480
2018-11-25  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    480
2018-11-26  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    480 *(Bank Holiday)*
2018-11-27  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    720
2018-11-28  00:00:00.0000000    00:00:00.0000000    0 *(fakeMaintenance)*
2018-11-29  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    720
2018-11-30  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    720
```

*Above table inspired by @donPablo*

Actually, Bank holidays and Sundays are now 9am to 5pm.

There are are also 2 additional columns [IsBankHoliday] and [IsNonWorkingDay] (generally maintenance).

Then I added the following to the DimDate procedure:

```
CASE 
    WHEN [nw].[NonWorkingDayDate] IS  NOT NULL
        THEN '00:00:00'
    ELSE '09:00:00'
END AS [StartTime],


CASE 
    WHEN [nw].[NonWorkingDayDate] IS  NOT NULL
        THEN '00:00:00'
    WHEN [bh].[BankHolidayDate] IS  NOT NULL or [DayOfWeekNumber] IN (6,7)
        THEN '17:00:00'
    ELSE '21:00:00'
END AS [EndTime],
```

Then, I created the following function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [Udf].[GenerateBreachTime] (@CompletionAt [datetime],
```

@Deadline [datetime])

```
SELECT (SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN @Deadline > @CompletionAt THEN -1
    WHEN CONVERT(varchar(8), @Deadline, 112) <= CONVERT(varchar(8), @CompletionAt, 112) THEN CASE   --NWD DC|| ||DC  = 0
        WHEN ([Non Working Day] = 1 AND
          CONVERT(varchar(8), @Deadline, 112) = CONVERT(varchar(8), [DateId], 112)) --nwd
          OR @Deadline > CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @Deadline), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [EndTime], 108)) AS datetime) --deadline after hours
          OR @CompletionAt < CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @Deadline), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [StartTime], 108)) AS datetime) THEN 0
        -- D|C|
        WHEN @Deadline < CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @Deadline), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [StartTime], 108)) AS datetime) AND
          @CompletionAt < CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @Deadline), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [EndTime], 108)) AS datetime) THEN DATEDIFF(n, CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @Deadline), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [StartTime], 108)) AS datetime), @CompletionAt)
        --D||C
        WHEN @Deadline < CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @Deadline), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [StartTime], 108)) AS datetime) AND
          @CompletionAt > CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @Deadline), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [EndTime], 108)) AS datetime) THEN DATEDIFF(n, CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @Deadline), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [StartTime], 108)) AS datetime), CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @Deadline), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [EndTime], 108)) AS datetime))
        -- |DC|
        WHEN @Deadline >= CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @Deadline), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [StartTime], 108)) AS datetime) AND
          @CompletionAt <= CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @Deadline), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [EndTime], 108)) AS datetime) THEN DATEDIFF(n, @Deadline, @CompletionAt)
        --|D|C
        WHEN @Deadline >= CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @Deadline), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [StartTime], 108)) AS datetime) AND
          @CompletionAt > CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @Deadline), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [EndTime], 108)) AS datetime) THEN DATEDIFF(n, @Deadline, CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @Deadline), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [EndTime], 108)) AS datetime))
        ELSE 0
      END
    ELSE 0
  END
  AS [BreachMins]
FROM [Vw].[Dim Date] DimDate
WHERE dateid = CONVERT(varchar(8), @Deadline, 112))
+ (SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN CONVERT(varchar(8), @Deadline, 112) >= CONVERT(varchar(8), @CompletionAt, 112) THEN 0
    WHEN CONVERT(varchar(8), @Deadline, 112) <= CONVERT(varchar(8), @CompletionAt, 112) THEN CASE
        -- C|| OR NWD
        WHEN @CompletionAt < CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @CompletionAt), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [StartTime], 108)) AS datetime) OR
          ([Non Working Day] = 1 AND
          CONVERT(varchar(8), @CompletionAt, 112) = CONVERT(varchar(8), [DateId], 112)) THEN 0
        -- |C|
        WHEN @CompletionAt <= CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @CompletionAt), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [EndTime], 108)) AS datetime)
        --THEN 1
        THEN DATEDIFF(n, CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @CompletionAt), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [StartTime], 108)) AS datetime), @CompletionAt)
        --||C
        WHEN @CompletionAt > CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @CompletionAt), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [EndTime], 108)) AS datetime)
        --THEN 2
        THEN DATEDIFF(n, CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @CompletionAt), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [StartTime], 108)) AS datetime), CAST(Concat(CONVERT(date, @CompletionAt), ' ', CONVERT(char(5), [EndTime], 108)) AS datetime))
        ELSE 0
      END
    ELSE 0
  END
  AS [BreachMins]
FROM [Vw].[Dim Date] DimDate
WHERE dateid = CONVERT(varchar(8), @CompletionAt, 112))
+ (SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN SUM(workingminsinday) IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE SUM(workingminsinday)
  END AS [x]
FROM vw.[Dim Date]
WHERE dateid BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar(8), @Deadline + 1, 112) AND CONVERT(varchar(8), @CompletionAt - 1, 112))

AS [BreachMins]
```

The daily procedure calls the function

```
        ,[BreachTime].[BreachInMins]
    FROM [Syn].[X]

      CROSS APPLY [udf].[GenerateBreachTime] ([Completed],[Deadline]) [BreachTime]
```

The subsequent view handles -1 cases, changing them to NULL.

I hope this helps someone else, and apologies if not entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

Create the Bank_Calendar table, which has EVERY bank date listed, and focuses on the Working times. It includes closed, holiday, and maintenance with Zero time.

```
BankDate    BankTimeStart       BankTimeEnd         BankDateDescription
2018-11-19  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    Mon
2018-11-20  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    Tue
2018-11-21  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    Wed
2018-11-22  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    Thu
2018-11-23  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    Fri
2018-11-24  11:00:00.0000000    15:00:00.0000000    Sat
2018-11-25  00:00:00.0000000    00:00:00.0000000    Sun closed
2018-11-26  00:00:00.0000000    00:00:00.0000000    Mon fakeBH1
2018-11-27  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    Tue
2018-11-28  00:00:00.0000000    00:00:00.0000000    Wed fakeMaintenance
2018-11-29  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    Thu
2018-11-30  09:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    Fri
```

And here is my rendition of table1, which has separate Date field from Time field to make later arithmetic easier

```
DC_ID   Deadline_Date   Deadline_Time   Completion_Date Completion_Time
    1   2018-11-24  14:55:00.0000000    2018-11-27  09:05:00.0000000
    2   2018-11-24  15:05:00.0000000    2018-11-27  09:04:00.0000000
    3   2018-11-27  11:00:00.0000000    2018-11-27  10:35:00.0000000
    4   2018-11-27  16:50:00.0000000    2018-11-29  09:10:00.0000000
    5   2018-11-22  09:05:00.0000000    2018-11-22  09:10:00.0000000
```

Here is the sql

```
select
    dc.*
    ,sum(
    Case when dc.Deadline_Date = cal.BankDate and dc.Completion_Date = cal.BankDate Then 
             --'SameDay'
             Datediff(n, dc.Deadline_Time, dc.Completion_Time)
          when dc.Deadline_Date = cal.BankDate and dc.Completion_Date <> cal.BankDate 
          and  dc.Deadline_Time > cal.BankTimeEnd Then
             --'FR' but Deadline is after Closing
             0 
          when dc.Deadline_Date = cal.BankDate and dc.Completion_Date <> cal.BankDate Then 
             --'FR' the remaining part of the day until closing
             Datediff(n, dc.Deadline_Time, cal.BankTimeEnd)
          when dc.Deadline_Date <> cal.BankDate and dc.Completion_Date <> cal.BankDate Then 
             --'allday' add the entire day  (for closings/holidays it becomes zero)
             Datediff(n, cal.BankTimeStart, cal.BankTimeEnd)
          when dc.Deadline_Date <> cal.BankDate and dc.Completion_Date = cal.BankDate Then 
             --'TO' add the beginning part of the day
             Datediff(n, cal.BankTimeStart, dc.Completion_Time)
      End )
      as minnn
from DateDiff_DeadlineCompletion as dc
Left Join DateDiff_Calendar as cal

On dc.Deadline_Date <= cal.BankDate
  and dc.Completion_Date >= cal.BankDate

Group By dc.DC_ID
         ,dc.Deadline_Date
         ,dc.Deadline_Time
         ,dc.Completion_Date
         ,dc.Completion_Time
```

And the results   (btw -- we get different answers for item 4)

```
DC_ID   Deadline_Date   Deadline_Time   Completion_Date Completion_Time minnn
1   2018-11-24  14:55:00.0000000    2018-11-27  09:05:00.0000000    10
2   2018-11-24  15:05:00.0000000    2018-11-27  09:04:00.0000000    4
3   2018-11-27  11:00:00.0000000    2018-11-27  10:35:00.0000000    -25
4   2018-11-27  16:50:00.0000000    2018-11-29  09:10:00.0000000    140
5   2018-11-22  09:05:00.0000000    2018-11-22  09:10:00.0000000    5
```